# Pegar a hora em um computador remoto usando C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Existe algum método para eu conseguir recuperar a hora e data de um computador remoto usando C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2836996/2221388 você já tentou essa resposta do SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu achei uma [solução usando WMI em resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585205/221800). Não gosta dela.

tem também uma [solução chamando o `net time`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18463639/221800), horrível pro meu gosto.

Tem outras soluções por lá.

Prefiro a [solução usando NTP em outra resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008145/221800). A [implementação exemplo pode ser vista aqui](http://dotnet-snippets.com/snippet/simple-network-time-ntp-protocol-client/571). Com o uso adotado em [outra resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8093462/221800):

```
InternetTime.SNTPClient sntp = new InternetTime.SNTPClient("ntp1.ja.net");
sntp.Connect(false); // true to update local client clock
DateTime dt = sntp.DestinationTimestamp.AddMilliseconds(sntp.LocalClockOffset);
var timeStampNow = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetInternetTime.cs).